# Time Series Expectation/Autocovariance Question

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

I have a stochastic process that's represented by $X_t = \epsilon_t \times \epsilon_{t-1}$ where $\epsilon_t$ ~ $N(0, \sigma^2)$ and iid. I'm asked to find the expected value of $X_t$ and the autocovariance function $\gamma(t, s)$ for all $s, t$.

I've worked out the problem, but I am not sure if this approach is right. For the expected value, I have:

\begin{equation}
E[X_t] = E[\epsilon_t\epsilon_{t-1}]= 0
\end{equation}

using the fact that:

\begin{equation}
cov(\epsilon_t, \epsilon_{t-1}) = E[\epsilon_t\epsilon_{t-1}] - E[\epsilon_t]E[\epsilon_{t-1}] = 0
\end{equation}

because $\epsilon_t$ and $\epsilon_{t-1}$ are independent and have mean 0. Is this logic correct?

Also, for $\gamma(t, s)$, I have:

\begin{equation}
cov(X_t, X_s) = cov(\epsilon_t\epsilon_{t-1}, \epsilon_s\epsilon_{s-1}) \\
= E(\epsilon_t\epsilon_{t-1}\epsilon_s\epsilon_{s-1}) - E(\epsilon_t\epsilon_{t-1})E(\epsilon_s\epsilon_{s-1}) \\
= E(\epsilon_t\epsilon_{t-1}\epsilon_s\epsilon_{s-1})
\end{equation}

since we found from before that $E(\epsilon_t\epsilon_{t-1}) = 0$. Then, because the $\epsilon_t$ are independent, the expectation of the product is just

\begin{equation}
E(\epsilon_t\epsilon_{t-1}\epsilon_s\epsilon_{s-1}) = E(\epsilon_t)E(\epsilon_{t_1})E(\epsilon_s)E(\epsilon_{s-1}) = 0
\end{equation}

because they all have mean 0. Is my approach defensible? It's been a while since I've been exposed to statistical properties--any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your last line, what happens if $s=t$?

Comment: I think it's for all s, t, so I'm not sure if that will impact anything.

Comment: If it didn't impact anything, then you have shown $\text{Var}(X_t)=0$, which is not true. The trick to computing the autocovariance function is usually to think about whether the $\varepsilon_t$ overlap or not, depending on the relative positions of $t$ and $s$.